# Maven fails to run Grails Spock integration tests

Tags: maven, grails, spock

For some reason the Maven Grails integration fails to run Spock (integration phase)* tests

The tests are executed fine with the normal grails command `grails test-app`,
but the Maven version `mvn grails:test-app` fails. I've followed [this example](http://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/HelloSpockPom) in the setup.

My grails `BuildConfig.groovy` has the following

```
dependencies {
  // ... irrelevant dependencies omitted
  test 'org.spockframework:spock-grails-support:0.7-groovy-2.0'
}

plugins {
  // ... irrelevant plugins omitted
  test(":spock:0.7") { exclude "spock-grails-support"
}
```

And the Maven pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spock.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>    
</dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
    <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${grails.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <fork>true</fork>
    </configuration>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spock-maven</artifactId>
    <version>${spock.version}</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>find-specs</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

where **Grails version is 2.2.4** and **Spock version is 0.7-groovy-2.0**

The bottom line is that the **Spock tests just don't get executed at all.** What's up with that?

* So far only have written integration phase tests with Spock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plugin dependencies should be specified in `pom.xml` instead of `BuildConfig` in mavenized projects. 
Replace entries for spock in `BuildConfig` (remove spock plugin and the dependency to the support jar as well) with the below entry in `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>spock</artifactId>
  <version>0.7</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
  <type>zip</type>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spock-grails-support</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spock-grails-support</artifactId>
  <version>0.7-groovy-2.0</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

You would not need `spock-maven` maven pluing as well, I suppose

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I got it working with your maven config. All the references mentioned in my question to Spock can be safely removed from BuildConfig

Comment: @JAndy You can modify the `<scope>` to `test` instead of `runtime`. I was facing some problem with `test` scope, so I had to default it to `runtime` (although runtime dependencies are also available during test)